# Linux: KDM, startx & the X session

Tags: linux, kde, xorg, kdm

I'm using startx in my `.bashrc` file to start X when I login at tty1 instead of using a display manager like KDM (I'm using KDE 4.3.4). The actual code in my `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ "`tty`" = /dev/tty1 ]
then
    startx
    logout
fi
```

Now the problem is since KDM is not running I'm not able to use the shut down button from the KDE menu (because it needs root privileges to do so) and some other features are gone as well.

Is there a way to start KDM when I run `startx` in my `.bashrc`, like just running KDM in the background? The point is that I want no login display, so I'm sure there must be a way to just start KDM *silently*.

Answer (score 1):

Putting startx in .bashrc is a **bad** idea. It will prevent you from being able to log in normally to a console. Unless you have a really, really good reason to do so (and I suspect that you, like pretty much everyone else, do not), use a display manager instead.

Comment: Exactly. Or do the extra seven keystrokes and run startx the normal way after you log in.

Answer (score 0):

you can set kdm to auto-login, so you'll see no login form displayed. would it help?
if it does help, you need to run systemsettings as root (alt+f2 => kdesu systemsettings) then in "login manager" under the "advanced tab" choose "enable auto login" in "convenience" tab.

Comment: The problem is that I still want my login prompt at tty1. If I start KDM using a auto-login I won't be prompted for a password at all (as far as I know?). What I want is to login via tty1 and then start X and run KDM in the background.

Comment: can you run 'sudo' on .bashrc? it should help you with the permissions issue. auto-login would do everything else once you start the KDM service (usually in /etc/init.d/kdm).

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you want to achieve, but like Ignacio wrote putting startx into your `.bashrc` is a *really bad* idea. If your problem were only that you cannot call `shutdown -h` from within that session, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>del</kbd> is usually mapped to `shutdown -r now` in `/etc/inittab`. You can change it to `shutdown -h now` in there as well.

If your problem is only that you *really, really badly* want to have `X` running on `tty1`, you can of course start `kdm` on `tty1`. Then you would also only have to give your login once (was that the issue?). To do that you need to modify a few files.

- `/etc/inittab`:

  Remove/comment the line that spawns the getty on `tty1`. It looks something like

  ```
  ## c1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty1 linux
  ```
- `/etc/conf.d/xdm`

  Tell the `xdm` scripts that they are working on `tty1`; change the entry in there to

  ```
  CHECKVT=1
  ```

To have `X` start automatically you of course need it in your default runlevel (added via `rc-update add xdm`).

Comment: Using `startx` in my `.bashrc` ain't that bad because I use `if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then startx; logout; fi` (sorry, I guess I wasn't precise enough there). Your idea with starting `kdm` on `tty1` might look like a acceptable solution. The main reason why I want the text login prompt, is that this way I'd be able to login as root as well, dropping into a shell f.e. for any kind of maintenance. And that's why I start X on `tty1` :).

Comment: @watain: for the scenary you mention there are 6 tty's available. Just for reference: Use CTRL-ALT F1..F6 to switch.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but that's not the point. I simply want to be able to use the text login at tty1 with my user to start X and on all other ttys to get the console after login.